# Why is currying mandatory in this function

Tags: haskell

```
oneone'' :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
oneone'' = map(+1) . filter ((==0) . (`mod` 2))
```

The code keeps even numbers from a list and adds one to each without using list comprehension.

Why is it that when I try to put a variable like `ns` to represent a list like so  `oneone'' ns` it breaks the function. Then if I try to put the ns anywhere inside the function IDE says the syntax is wrong.

From what I understand this `(==0) . (`mod `2)` is executed first because of `.`

So why can't it be written as

```
oneone'' ns = map(+1) . filter ((==0) . (`mod` 2) ns )
```

if you can just refference me to some topics about this that would be cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you have the `ns` inside the parentheses. In particular what you have there, inside the parentheses (which has to be a well-typed expression in itself) is

```
(==0) . (`mod` 2) ns
```

which could also be written as

```
(==0) . (ns `mod` 2)
```

which makes no sense as the expression on the right of the `.` is a number (or it would be if `ns` was a number, although in actual fact it's a list of numbers, which is another problem), and `.` needs to have a function on either side.

What you instead wanted was:

```
oneone'' ns = (map(+1) . filter ((==0) . (`mod` 2))) ns
```

In general, if you have `f = g` then (if `f` and `g` are functions) you also have `f x = g x` for any `x` which the function accepts. (Note that if `f` and/or `g` are complex expressions then you need to separate them from the `x` with parentheses - so really it's `(f) x = (g) x` - see @amalloy's comment below.) But this doesn't allow you to just put the `x` (corresponding to `ns` in your code) inside any parentheses that may be involved in `f` or `g`, which is what you were doing.

Comment: `f = g . h` is not equivalent to `f x = g . h x`, as you've written, but to `f x = (g . h) x`.

Comment: I mean your definition for `oneone''` needs more parentheses: `oneone'' ns = (map(+1) . filter ((==0) . (`mod` 2))) ns`.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the idiomatic is of `$` in this context.

Comment: I actually consider this a flaw in Haskell syntax - the complex rules for comining `.`, `$` and currying, while making sense from an implementation point of view, are not exactly easy to use.